# How to prevent CheckedListBox ItemCheck from infinite loop (VB)?

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

I am having an issue with the ItemCheck event for my CheckedListBox.  The CheckedListBox has many items, plus an 'All' item at the top.

I want to handle the 3 situations below, but I am getting an infinite loop error.  Any ideas how to prevent this from happening?  Thanks in advance.

(1)  Check/uncheck every item when 'All' item is checked/unchecked

(2)  Unchecked 'All' item if any single item is unchecked

(3)  Check 'All' item if all items are checked

```
If e.CurrentValue <> e.NewValue Then
    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
        If e.Index = 0 Then
            For i = 1 To .Items.Count - 1
                .SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked)
            Next
        Else
            If .CheckedItems.Count >= .Items.Count - 1 Then
                .SetItemCheckState(i, True)
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If e.Index = 0 Then
            For i = 1 To .Items.Count - 1
                .SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked)
            Next
        Else
            .SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Unchecked)
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the event handler, perform your changes, then add it back in:

```
With CheckedListBox1
  RemoveHandler .ItemCheck, AddressOf CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck
  Dim i As Integer
  If e.CurrentValue <> e.NewValue Then
    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
      If e.Index = 0 Then
        For i = 1 To .Items.Count - 1
          .SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked)
        Next
      Else
        If .CheckedItems.Count >= .Items.Count - 1 Then
          .SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked)
        End If
      End If
    Else
      If e.Index = 0 Then
        For i = 1 To .Items.Count - 1
          .SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked)
        Next
      Else
        .SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Unchecked)
      End If
    End If
  End If
  AddHandler .ItemCheck, AddressOf CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck
End With
```

Comment: Be also careful with the "CheckedItems.Count" that doesn't include the updated Item, because "*the check state is not updated until after the ItemCheck event occurs*".

Comment: @Graffito I don't see the issue since the OP's code is using the e.CurrentValue and e.NewValue properties.

Comment: @Graffito There aren't any items being added or removed during this method, so still, there is no issue since the code is using the `e.CurrentValue` and `e.NewValue` properties, which *are updated* in the ItemCheck event.